# WordPress Gravity Forms: Require Exact Text Match

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

On my Gravity Form I have a single line text field that says:

> Our coaching team WILL call you at the time you chose. Please commit
>   to your appointment by typing this sentence in the box below: "Yes, I
>   promise I will answer the phone for my Breakthrough Session when my
>   coach calls."

How can I make the text field show an error unless that EXACT text is entered?

I have tried using a custom input mask but that only allows for a text and number pattern, not an exact text match.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Use conditional logic on the Submit button to hide it until that exact string is entered.

**Solution 2**

Set the default value of a Hidden field on your form to the exact string you want. Use the [Custom Field Confirmation](https://gravitywiz.com/custom-field-confirmation/) snippet to make sure the user enters that exact string in another field.